# Explanation of ayat 17:70

Tags: tafseer

> Indeed, We have dignified the children of Adam, carried them on land and sea, granted them good and lawful provisions, and privileged them far above many of Our creatures.
>
> [Quran 17:70](https://quran.com/17/70?translations=20)

Does this ayat shows that humans are not superior to all creatures ? Then what are those other creatures?

Answer (score 1):

The apparent wording of this verse suggests that there is creation which is equal or superior to humans. There can be a number of examples, for example the angels who as a whole are superior to humans (excluding the prophets).

> وإن ذكرني في ملأ ذكرته في ملأ خير منهم
>
> If he remembers Me in a group of people, I remember him in a group that is better than they
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:7405)</sup>

However some exegetes have also claimed that كثير can at times mean all, such as in [26:223](https://quran.com/26/223?translations=20) and  [16:83](https://quran.com/16/83?translations=20).

Ref:  [Tafsir al-Baghawy](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/baghawy/sura17-aya70.html)